# Why do Perl 6 state variable behave differently for different files?

Tags: variables, initialization, state, raku

I have 2 test files. In one file, I want to extract the middle section using a state variable as a switch, and in the other file, I want to use a state variable to hold the sum of numbers seen.

File one:

```
section 0; state 0; not needed
= start section 1 =
state 1; needed
= end section 1 =
section 2; state 2; not needed
```

File two:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Code to process file one:

```
cat file1 | perl6 -ne 'state $x = 0; say " x is ", $x; if $_ ~~ m/ start / { $x = 1; }; .say if $x == 1; if $_ ~~ m/ end / { $x = 2; }'
```

and the result is with errors:

```
 x is (Any)
Use of uninitialized value of type Any in numeric context
  in block  at -e line 1
 x is (Any)
= start section 1 =
 x is 1
state 1; needed
 x is 1
= end section 1 =
 x is 2
 x is 2
```

And the code to process file two is

```
cat file2 | perl6 -ne 'state $x=0; if $_ ~~ m/ \d+ / { $x += $/.Str; } ; say $x; '
```

and the results are as expected:

```
1
3
6
10
15
```

**What make the state variable fail to initialize in the first code, but okay in the second code?**

I found that in the first code, **if I make the state variable do something**, such as addition, then it works. Why so?

```
cat file1 | perl6 -ne 'state $x += 0; say " x is ", $x; if $_ ~~ m/ start / { $x = 1; }; .say if $x == 1; if $_ ~~ m/ end / { $x = 2; }'

# here, $x += 0 instead of $x = 0; and the results have no errors:

 x is 0
 x is 0
= start section 1 =
 x is 1
state 1; needed
 x is 1
= end section 1 =
 x is 2
 x is 2
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Looks like a Rakudo bug. Simpler test-case: `echo Hello | perl6 -ne 'state $x = 42; dd $x'`. It seems that top-level state variables are not initialized when the `-n` or `-p` switch is used. Please [report the bug](http://rakudo.org/tickets/) if you haven't already. As a work-around, you can manually initialize the variable in a separate statement, using the `//=` (assign if undefined) operator: `state $x; $x //= 42;`

Comment: Thank you smls !! I will report this bug !

Comment: @smls I'm creating an answer from your comment. Feel free to do the same thing (it is your comment after all) and then I'll delete my answer. (I'm trying to get this off of the "unanswered" list).

Answer (score 2):

This was answered in smls's comment:

> Looks like a Rakudo bug. Simpler test-case:
>   `echo Hello | perl6 -ne 'state $x = 42; dd $x'`.
>   It seems that top-level state variables are
>   not initialized when the `-n` or `-p` switch is used. As a work-around, you can manually initialize the variable in a separate statement, using the `//=` (assign if undefined) operator:
>   `state $x; $x //= 42;`